# ScenePointToLocalPointInRectangle no longer works after reloading scene

Tags: unity, gui

I have created a GUI that floats over an object. However, when I reload the scene, the `ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle()` function does not work and acts as if I used `WorldToScreenPoint()` instead. [Here is a video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-pMCdMogy9MvinDnQnnxaEHWGE1UUFPP/view?usp=share_link) showing the problem I'm facing.

This is my current code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class GUI : MonoBehaviour
{
  public GameObject pressgui;
  public Image image;
  public float Radius;
  float x1,x2,y1,y2,ex,ey,vx,vy,cx,cy,tx,ty;
  float offset;
  int reverse;
  Vector3 reverseR;

  void Awake() {
      offset = 20f;
      x1 = Screen.width/2*-1+offset;
      x2 = Screen.width/2-offset;
      y1 = Screen.height/2*-1+offset;
      y2 = Screen.height/2-offset;
  }
  
  void Update() {
    pressgui.active = false;
    image.enabled = true;
    Vector3 loc = transform.position;
    var screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position + new Vector3(0.5f,2,0));
    
    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(loc,Radius);
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(
        (RectTransform)pressgui.transform.parent, // pressgui's container
        screenPosition ,          // position measured in pixels
        null,                    // use this for Screen Space - Overlay canvas
        out Vector2 uiPosition // local UI space position
    ); 
    foreach (Collider hit in colliders){
        if(hit.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
            image.enabled = false;
            pressgui.active = true;
            pressgui.transform.localPosition = uiPosition;
        }
    }
  
    reverse = 180;
    reverseR = -Vector3.forward;
    vx = uiPosition.x;
    vy = uiPosition.y;
    if (vx > 0 )ex = x2; else ex = x1;
    if (vy > 0 ){ey = y2;} else {ey = y1;}
    if (vx == 0 )cx = 0;cy = ey;
    if (vy == 0 )cx = ex;cy = 0;
    tx = (ex - 0) / vx;
    ty = (ey - 0) / vy;
    if (tx <= ty ){ cx = ex; cy = 0 + tx * vy; }else{ cx = 0 + ty * vx;  cy = ey;}
    image.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(cx,cy);
  
    if(screenPosition.z<0){
        image.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(image.transform.localPosition.x*-1, image.transform.localPosition.y*-1);
        reverse = 0;
        gyakuu = Vector3.forward;
    }
    var dir = new Vector2(0,0) - new Vector2(image.transform.localPosition.x,image.transform.localPosition.y);
    var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.x,dir.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - reverse;  
    image.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle,reverseR);
  }
}
```

Here's my *Image* setup:

[image: 1]

*Canvas* setup:

[image: 2]

And the object to which the script is attached:

[image: 3]

Comment: Usually this is a symptom of one of the objects you were referencing getting unloaded. Check whether `pressgui` is null here. (In general: *always* check for null when something mysteriously stops working - it rarely has anything to do with the code attempting to *use* the null, and everything to do with the code that *made* the reference null, or failed to repopulate it)

Comment: @DMGregory: I debugged it, both before and after reloading. `guican (UnityEngine.RectTransform) Debug:Log (object)` was displayed.

Comment: I notice you no longer have an `if` check skipping this unless the player is close. Is it possible that multiple objects are running this script after a reload and fighting over where tp place `pressgui`? We'll need you to update the question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem: every line of code and every step of scene setup needed to reproduce the problem in a new, empty project. Strip out anything not required, to keep this as lean as possible. Once we can reproduce the problem, we can test solutions to be sure they'll work for your situation.

Comment: @DMGregory: I used "Find Reference In Scene" to find conflicts, but it only attaches to one object.

Comment: When I say every line of code and every step of scene setup, the *every* is very important. The code above will not compile because we don't have the declaration of `checkpoint`, `image`, `loc`, `radius`, etc. To ensure you are sharing a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, create a new, empty project. Add to the project *only* the content that is explicitly described in your question. If that project does not compile, run, and demonstrate the problem, you have not finished making your MCVE yet.

Comment: We're still lacking the instructions to set up a scene with this script, `image`, and `pressgui` set up in such a way as to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DMGregory: Excuse me, what exactly do I have to do?

Comment: I've explained to you multiple times now. A reader needs to be able to use ONLY the information in your question to create a new project that demonstrates this problem. If you have not told them where to attach this script, or what to assign to its inspector fields, then they cannot succeed at that task.

Comment: @DMGregory: Changing the screen size was also found to cause the UI to move incorrectly.